# How to change category filter position in magento layer navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7,

I have four filter in layer on left sidebar of category page.

They are listed as

categorie  brands size  color.

I want to change category and brands position I want brands to position first like as follows.

brands categories size color.

How can I do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Attributes which is using in layered navigation and there is field/textbox to add position values Under Front End properties.

Put position as per your requirement.

Then reindex also.

If want to set Category filter position, then follow these steps:

Copy file: `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php`
Paste file: `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php`

Then Update code of `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php` file.

Replace `getFilters()` function code with below code:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    $catFilters = array(); // Created New array
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $catFilters[] = $categoryFilter; // Assign category to new array
    }

    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
    }

    /* Pushed category filter array to position 1, if want to change position then update value in this function. */
    array_splice( $filters, 1, 0, $catFilters ); 
    return $filters;
}
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: your solution is correct for attribute filter but category is not attribute. I have added this position field but it didn't work. I was not able to give position to category filter.

Comment: @user2293790, I have updated answer. follow these steps to put category filter at desire position. You need to copy Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View block file to local directory so that core code will not affected.